# Navigating terms aggregation in Elastic with very large number of buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Hope everyone is staying safe!

I am trying to explore the proper way to tacke the following use case in elasticsearch

Lets say that I have about 700000 docs which I would like to bucket on the basis of a field (let's call it primary_id). This primary id can be same for more than one docs (usually upto 2-3 docs will have same primary_id). In all other cases the primary_id is not repeted in any other docs.

So on average out of every 10 docs I will have 8 unique primary ids, and 1 primary id same among 2 docs

To ensure uniqueness I tried using the terms aggregation and I ended up getting buckets in response to my search request but not for the subsequent scroll requests. Upon googling, I found that scroll queries do not support aggregations.

As a result, I tried finding alternates solutions, and tried the solution in this link as well, https://lukasmestan.com/learn-how-to-use-scroll-elasticsearch-aggregation/

It suggests use of multiple search requests each specifying the partition number to fetch (dependent upon how many partitions do you divide your result in). But I receive client timeouts even with high timeout settings client side.

Ideally, I want to know what is the best way to go about such data where the variance of the field which forms the bucket is almost equal to the number of docs. The SQL equivalent would be select DISTINCT ( primary_id) from .....

But in elasticsearch, distinct things can only be processed via bucketing (terms aggregation).

I also use top hits as a sub aggregation query under terms aggregation to fetch the _source fields.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to paginate aggregtation.

1. Composite aggregation
2. Partition
3. Bucket sort

Partition you have already tried.

[Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html): can combine **multiple datasources** in a single buckets and allow pagination and sorting on it. It can only paginate linearly using after_key i.e you cannot jump from page 1 to page 3. You can fetch "n" records , then pass returned after key and fetch next "n" records.

```
GET index22/_search
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "ValueCount": {
     "value_count": {
       "field": "id.keyword"
     }
   },
   "pagination": {
     "composite": {
       "size": 2,
       "sources": [
         {
           "TradeRef": {
             "terms": {
               "field": "id.keyword"
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Bucket sort

> The bucket_sort aggregation, like all pipeline aggregations, is
>   executed after all other non-pipeline aggregations. This means the
>   sorting only applies to whatever buckets are already returned from the
>   parent aggregation. For example, if the parent aggregation is terms
>   and its size is set to 10, the bucket_sort will only sort over those
>   10 returned term buckets

So this isn't suitable for your case

You can increase the result size to value greater than 10K by updating setting  index.max_result_window. Setting too big a size can cause out of memory issue so you need to test it out see how much your hardware can support.

Better option is to use scroll api and perform distinct at client side

Comment: Using this I will have to make aroung 700 requests requesting 10k docs each time to be able to retrieve everything. Is that recommended? Also the documentation specifies,

" If all composite buckets should be retrieved it is preferable to use a small size (100 or 1000 for instance) and then use the after parameter to retrieve the next results."

Is that for I/O optimization purposes (I would guess yes) In which case I might end up making about 7k search requests each requesting 1k docs.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Clearly it doesn' seem viable to be making that many search requests, so i guess I will have to approach the issue from some other perspective.

Comment: I was reading some other answers and someone suggesed using field collapsing feature. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse
But I am not sure how it will work because using collapse on a highly cardinality field leaves me uncertain whether the collapsed key (primary_id) would have considered each and every doc in the index or not. Also I am not sure if it will work with scroll request

Comment: @NamanGupta Collapse will not work with scroll. collapse is like group by on a field but unfortunately scrll doesn't support it

Comment: Just realized it, what a bummer :(
It was exactly what I needed. Not sure what to do now

Comment: @NamanGupta I think you can increase max_result_window size and  use composite aggregation

Comment: my use case can actually warrant a total of around 70 Lakh (70,00,000) docs , and I suspect increasing that max_result_window to that much would have severe performance, stability implications.

Comment: @NamanGupta probably use scroll and perform distinct at api/client end